# Macbook: Audio cuts out every couple of minutes

Tags: mac, usb, audio, macbook

I'm using my MBP 2017 along with my USB Audio Interface (Presonus Audiobox iTwo) and I've been having some problems for a while.

Let me describe the issue: I have both my headphones and my microphone plugged to the interface, so I can both hear and record from it. Every minute or two, the sound goes completely off (it doesn't matter if I'm watching a video, listening to a track, or recording) AND it stops recording, then after a second (or a fraction of it) the sound comes back. It's like if some audio process goes completely off for half a second, and restarts immediately. I don't have the same issue when I'm using bluetooth speakers.

I don't think there's a problem with the interface, since it works well on my PC. The driver is up to date (reinstalled multiple times), and I'm on the latest version of BigSur. Yesterday I tried resetting the SMC and to my surprise, the issue was gone. I almost cried. One day after, the problem still persists. I have done nothing strange with the Macbook, I just think the problem reoccurs after a while or after the Mac has been sleeping. The fact that the issue was gone also suggests me that there's no problem with the interface, I'm almost 100% sure the problem is with my Macbook.

One thing I tried was changing the USB port to which the interface was connected, as I thought that maybe it wasn't getting the power it needed. But I noticed that while the audio from my Macbook cuts out, I can still hear myself speaking from the headphones, so the interface is working properly and never turning itself off even just for a few seconds.

Please, I don't know what to do anymore. What could it be? Here's what comes to mind:

- I tried connecting the interface to the external monitor (it shares USB ports with the Macbook) and also to a dongle, and the problem persists. Maybe it needs a powered usb hub? I don't think so, the interface keeps working and never shuts down.
- Could it be a clock sync problem that occurs because of the USB->Thunderbolt conversion? But I don't know how I can debug it, and I don't get why the problem goes away after restarting the Macbook.
- I've seen articles about this kind of problem on new Macbooks with T2 chip, mine doesn't have it. However they mention that there's something going on with the USB bus, maybe it could be my case?

I'm thinking about getting a new interface but I'm not sure because I don't think that's the issue. This interface works properly on my Windows PC so I'm thinking either of a Macbook software problem, or a Macbook hardware problem, or a problem with the fact that USB and Thunderbolt don't get along. In that case, using a Thunderbolt2 interface with a Thunderbolt2->Thunderbolt3 adapter maybe could solve the problem? I don't know.

It's even difficult for me to debug because I don't really know what to do and the problem seems to disappear after I restart the Macbook, so every solution which involves restarting requires something like a day or two to be proven successful. What a pain.

Comment: Thunderbolt isn't a factor here. If you plug a USB device into a Thunderbolt 3 capable port, the connection uses pure USB; no Thunderbolt is involved.

Comment: Does this happen only after sleep, or even if the Mac is always awake? Some USB audio devices only hook up to the Mac correctly at boot & not after any 'pause'. idk specifically for the Presonus, but Line6 devices do that. I also have a cheapo optical>5.1 device on one of the Mac Pros here which does it too, after sleep. My main 'pro-audio' Mac never sleeps & this never happens.

Comment: @Tetsujin Well I honestly don't know! I never keep my MBP awake for more than 24 hours. I never put it to sleep via software: when I'm done working at night, I just close the lid and I open it the next day. I don't know if this changes anything :/

Comment: "It might"… is the best I can say ;) I know the old Mac Pros don't like being slept with a 'pro' USB preamp connected, but I really don't know about laptops. You could try leaving it awake & see if it makes the difference.

Comment: @Spiff Maybe there could be a problem with how the Mac distinguishes between usb and thunderbolt? Just thinking out loud. Also, maybe the problem is not the "conversion" as you say, but it could be related to the USB bus? If it is, buying a new interface with TB2 with a TB2->TB3 adapter could solve the issue for me. But buying another interface is honestly the last thing I'd do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guys I finally solved it. What. A. Nightmare. It's been 2 stressful months. I hope this helps someone else.

So, I used the Mac's Console (never knew it existed) and captured the error as it was happening: `coreaudiod HALS_IOa1Engine EndWriting got an error from the kernel trap 0xE00002D7`.

A quick search showed a lot of articles, everybody with a problem similar to mine. The general answer was to put a hub between the interface and the Mac, but I already did it because I had to, until... Someone said "**I've heard removing other USB devices helps. I removed my printer and the problem was gone**".

Well then. **I surely had a USB printer connected on the back of my secondary monitor**, which shares USB ports with the Macbook. I disconnected it. The problem was gone. Oh my god. Now I understand why I've been having this problem for months at random: it only occurs when the printer is connected.

Surely enough there's something going on with the USB bus, I don't know what, but it seems that when I plug in the printer the sound glitches for a second and then the issue persists. Once I disconnect it, the issue goes away. The strange thing is that if I connect the printer to the same hub as the interface (the dongle), the issue doesn't occur. I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that the Macbook doesn't like having the interface in one port and the printer connected to the monitor.

Obviously a fix would be highly appreciated (now I have to be careful when I connect anything via USB to the Macbook) but at least the issue is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a USB hub between the Presonus box and your MBP. Presonus has [previously acknowledged](https://support.presonus.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000057246-MacBook-Pro-Late-2016-Compatibility-Qualification) that some of their USB audio interfaces glitch out when directly connected to recent MacBook Pro designs. I'm pretty sure those MBP designs use standard Intel chips to run their Thunderbolt 3 / USB Type-C ports, and I don't hear about this happening with other vendors' USB audio interfaces, so I don't know what the deal is with Presonus' products, but the "put some other USB hub in between" workaround is cheap and easy to test.

Comment: I read that previously but the thing is... The dongle I use is just like a hub, isn't it? It's a dongle with USB/SD/HDMI ports that goes into USB-C (one of the TB3 ports of my Macbook). There's no way to have a direct connection between the interface and my MBP. Do they mean something else? Maybe a powered hub?

Comment: @MicheleStieven Hmm, yes, the port replicator dongle and the display with USB ports would both have internal USB hubs. But then again, whatever USB hub chips they're using could be where the problem actually is, I suppose. It would be interesting to get a passive [USB Type-C male to USB Type-A female adapter](https://www.amazon.com/Syntech-Adapter-Thunderbolt-Compatible-MacBook/dp/B07CVX3516/) so you can plug your audio interface directly into your MBP to eliminate possible interop problems with your port replicator dongle or your display's USB hub chip.

Comment: Seems like the problem is gone, see my answer :) Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found there are two options to control volume for sound and microphone. But the volumes were set as different for both output and input. I set the volumes as same. After then, this sound cut symptom disappeared